# React buttons, With tone.Js, breaking after first key pres,Error: Invalid argument(s) to setValueAtTime: {}, 2.2188208616780045

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tone.js

getting tones for the first button press then, I get this error...

Error: Invalid argument(s) to setValueAtTime: {}, 2.2188208616780045

not sure where this error comes from, I set the time with each mouse event, so this should be preventing any errors.

my Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import ButtonGroup from "react-bootstrap/ButtonGroup";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

import * as Tone from "tone";

const synth = new Tone.Synth().toDestination();

//
//container component to hold the piano keys
//
class PianoBoard extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseUp = this.handleMouseUp.bind(this);
  }

  handleMouseDown(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);
    Tone.start();
    synth.triggerAttack(e.target.attributes.note,Tone.now());
  }

  handleMouseUp(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);
    
    synth.triggerRelease(Tone.now());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="pianoboard">
        <Button onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown} onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp} note="C4">
          C4
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PianoBoard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from your tone attribute. You should pass the `note` to the mouse down function directly instead of trying to get the attribute `note` of the event.

```js
...
...
handleMouseDown(e, note){
  e.preventDefault(e);
  Tone.start();
  synth.triggerAttack(note,Tone.now());
}
...
...
<Button 
  onMouseDown={e => this.handleMouseDown(e, "C4")} 
  onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
>
  C4
</Button>
```